# audiofile content changes when uploaded to google cloud storage

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, google-cloud-storage, mp3, wav

I'm uploading an `MP3` file to google cloud storage then converting it to a `WAV` file and saving the result to cloud storage. The problem now is when i try to read the `WAV` file with `scipy.io` an error is thrown --> `Unexpected end of file`

i then converted my MP3 file **locally** and uploaded it to cloud storage and called it and opened it like i did with the other one and everything worked as expected.

After that i noticed despite the conversion was done with the same script, the two files have the same size and when opened by a media player they have same length and it seems there is no difference in the sound quality, but when converting them into strings and printing them in the console shows that they're not identical.

**NOTES :**

- MP3 file uploaded to cloud using a html form and saved with type audio/mpeg
- WAV file was converted using the following code and saved with type audio/Wav :

  ```
   const remoteWriteStream =

   storage.bucket(bucketName).file("path/to/file/file.wav")

  .createWriteStream({
      contentType: 'audio/wav'
  })

  ffmpeg(audioContent)
      .withAudioChannels(1)
      .toFormat('wav')
      .on('error', (err) => {
          console.log("error while conversion " + err)
          reject(err)
      })
      .on('progress', (progress) => {
          console.log("conversion in progress")
      })
      .on('end', () => {
          console.log("conversion from mp3 to wav finished")
          resolve()
      })
      .pipe(remoteWriteStream, { end: true })
  ```
- code to convert file locally :

  ```
  ffmpeg(mp3File)
  .withAudioChannels(1)
  .toFormat('wav')
  .on('error', (err) => {
      console.log("error while conversion " + err)
      reject(err)
  })
  .on('progress', (progress) => {
      console.log("conversion in progress")
  })
  .on('end', () => {
      console.log("conversion from mp3 to wav finished")
      resolve()
  })
  .save('path/to/save/file/file.wav')
  ```
- Conversion is done with `JavaScript` in both cases and calling and opening the waV file is done with `python`
- code to call and open WAV file from cloud :

`wavBucketFileBlob = bucket.get_blob('path/to/file/in/cloud/file.wav')`
`wavBucketFileString = wavBucketFileBlob.download_as_string()`

`rate,audio = wavfile.read(io.BytesIO(wavBucketFileString))`

**EDIT : **

I think the problem is in the header :

wav file that can't be read (saved in the cloud as audio/wav) :

```
b'RIFF$\x01A\x01WAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x88X\x01\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00LIST\xf8\x00\x00\x00INFOIART\n\x00\x00\x00Cat Power\x00ICMT6\x00\x00\x00https://open.spotify.com/track/2ilo3w0stilJKeQZS61FeN\x00ICOP\x1d\x00\x00\x002018 Domino Recording Co Ltd\x00\x00ICRD\x05\x00\x00\x002018\x00\x00IGNR\x08\x00\x00\x00Art Pop\x00INAM\x05\x00\x00\x00Stay\x00\x00IPRD\t\x00\x00\x00Wanderer\x00\x00IPRT\x05\x00\x00\x006/11\x00\x00ISFT\x0e\x00\x00\x00Lavf58.24.100\x00ITCH\x14\x00\x00\x00Domino Recording Co\x00data\x00\x00A\x01\x00\
```

wav file that can be read (saved in the cloud automatically when uploaded as audio/x-wav):

```
b'RIFF\xff\xff\xff\xffWAVEfmt \x10\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00D\xac\x00\x00\x88X\x01\x00\x02\x00\x10\x00LIST\xf8\x00\x00\x00INFOIART\n\x00\x00\x00Cat Power\x00ICMT6\x00\x00\x00https://open.spotify.com/track/2ilo3w0stilJKeQZS61FeN\x00ICOP\x1d\x00\x00\x002018 Domino Recording Co Ltd\x00\x00ICRD\x05\x00\x00\x002018\x00\x00IGNR\x08\x00\x00\x00Art Pop\x00INAM\x05\x00\x00\x00Stay\x00\x00IPRD\t\x00\x00\x00Wanderer\x00\x00IPRT\x05\x00\x00\x006/11\x00\x00ISFT\x0e\x00\x00\x00Lavf58.24.100\x00ITCH\x14\x00\x00\x00Domino Recording Co\x00data\xff\xff\xff\xff\
```

I tried when converting my mp3 to wav to save it as audio/x-wav since that seems to work but that was not the case.. i was still having the same problem.

**My workaround :**

I was using `scipy.io` to open read the wav file so i switched to `soundfile` which solved my problem but with a downside --> the quality of my output after doing further processing seems to be lower (but not really noticeable) than when i use `scipy.io`

Comment: Do you have an idea of what the difference between the two files is? I wonder if there's something very noticeable that might point to a cause, like some particular one byte is constantly changed to zeroes or something.

Comment: I updated my question with the difference i noticed between the two files and the workaround that i found. I would like to understand the reason behind this. Any explanation is much appreciated.

Comment: The "cksize" in the second example is \xff\xff\xff\xff, which makes me think that the problem is that scipy.io doesn't know how large the wave is going to be when it starts streaming it to GCS, somehow causing problems down the line.

Comment: interesting.. i wonder why there is a slight difference in quality if the two files are the same. Is it due to how `scipy.io` and `soundfile` interpret the input ? I'll just live with it for the time being. Thanks for the explanation